# What is the mathematical formula for N choose (k or j)

Tags: probability, permutations

I know the formula for a permutation is,  nPk = n!/(n-k)!. Is there a formula for a permutation of N choose k or j.

Here is an example of what I mean:
Say you have 5 objects and I can choose 1 or 2 of them, how many different ways can you choose 1 or 2 of the objects.

11111  221
1112   122
1121   212
2111   1211

So this example would have 8 distinct ways of choosing.

Comment: Please clarify in your example how you are choosing one or two objects.

Comment: What exactly do you want clarification on?

Comment: So, you want to know how many ways you can write $N=a_1+\dotsb+a_n$, where $a_i\in\{j,k\}$ for all $i$. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes that is correct!

Comment: Let's stick to $\{1,2\}$ for a second. Let's denote this by $f(N)$. So, you just showed $f(5)=8$. Try listing $f(N)$ for a few $N$ — you'll see a nice pattern! :)

Comment: f(N) = f(N) + f(N-1) is the pattern, but what is f(n)?

Answer (score 1):

HINT:  You can come up with a recursive formula for target $n$ with $k$ numbers to choose if all your numbers are either 0,1,or 2. by noting that depending on whether the last number is 0,1, or 2, this gives

$$f_{k,n+2} = f_{k-1,n+2} + f_{k-1,n+1} + f_{k-1,n}$$

with obvious initial conditions.